# SQL Left Join one to many

Tags: php, mysql

I have been lurking for a long time and so surprised at how many answers I get without asking a question but I have yet to find an answer to what I'm looking for.

Question is, I have 3 tables that I need to join. Table 1 is a collection of items and is the main table. Table 2 is a table the displays the condition of the items from Table 1 and will be joined to see what the values correspond to (table 1, column would be condition and value will be 1, left join to table 2 will make value 1 be "New"). Table 3 stores which items you own, there could be from 0 to infinite and takes the Table 1 IND and left joins it to Table 3 "Table1IND".

My problem is that I'm trying to return all Rows from table 1 that has a corresponding table 3 entry (Table1.ind = Table3.Table1IND) but this will return multiple Table 1 for multiple Table 3. This is a one (Table 1) to many (Table 3). I have tried to use an (Table1.ind in (select table1ind from Table 3) but the database is very large and this has showed some slow down in the processing, nothing majorly but after implementing this, maybe doubled the time, 5 to 10 maybe 15 seconds.

Little back info, database is MySQL and the item loading the data is PHP.

I appreciate all the help and let me know if you need anything else.

An example would be this:

```
select I.IND, T.Name as TName, I.Name as IName
from Items I
    left join Type T on I.Type = T.IND
    left join Own O on I.IND = O.ItemsIND and O.Username = 'removed this for other purposes'
where I.Name like '%%'
    and (O.IND is not null)
    and (T.TypeName = 'New')
order by T.Name, I.Name limit 100
```

Comment: Please include the exact queries you reference in the third paragraph.

Comment: Also consider in adding your tables structure. It would be easier to help you. Some data sample from the tables are also good to clarify your problem.

Comment: If I understand correctly, it works but it is slow?

Comment: Updated to show the code. The code runs but returns Items row twice if Own has 2 rows in it.

Comment: Are you getting duplicates where the T.IND is different or are you getting multiple rows with the same Item in New condition?  In either case, you're going to need to group by I.IND (and possibly T.IND) and aggregate O.ItemsIND with a SUM().

Comment: I added "distinct" after select and this gave me the results I'm looking for but I thought when you did a left join, it was only supposed to show all the data from table 1 and any data it matches with on everything else. Is that correct?

Comment: I'm getting multiple I.INDs. Lets says one item is a "DVD" (I.IND) and you have 2 "DVDS" in Table 3. It will show 2 I.IND for this one thing instead of 1 just for "DVDS"

Comment: It doesn't look as though you want results with null values, so you may want inner joins instead (at least going by your where statement).

Comment: I have to options for this search. I have a button says "Own" and it will generate the (O.IND is not null) and if the button isn't clicked, then it would show the whole list. So I'm trying to recycle the search without adding more code to do the same thing. But the distinct is exactly what I needed.